# Probability of guessing outcomes

Tags: probability

So we want to guess the outcomes of football games. For every game there are three possibilities:
 - Home wins (H)
 - Guests win (G)
 - The game is a tie (T)
We assume that the probability of guessing correctly is 1/3 every game, and each guess is independent of the previous. There are 9 games in the season.
I want to know the probability of guessing correctly on the outcome of at least 3 games, and then n games. This approach made sense to me:

$P(\geqslant 3) = 1 - P(<3)$, which should be $1-(P(0)+P(1)+P(2))$, meaning

$P(\geqslant3) = 1 - (\frac{2}{3})^9-\frac{1}{3}(\frac{2}{3})^8-(\frac{1}{3})^2(\frac{2}{3})^7 \approx 0.954$

There are independent events, and I thought I understood it. This is apparently not correct. What am I doing wrong here? Also if you have the time, could I get some tips on calculating expected outcomes and variance in these sorts of problems? Any answers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look up the [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).  For example:  $P(2)=\binom 92\times \left(\frac 13\right)^2\times \left(\frac 23\right)^7$.  As to mean and variance, once you have all the probabilities explicitly, these can simply be computed by using the standard definitions.

Comment: Thank you so much!